Is a doctor recommendation for reduced work hours (granted by the employeer) a case of "medical license"?
A federal civil servant in Brazil has been given a special work schedule in the form of a reduction of work hours by 50%.  This is a right given by article 98 of Law 8112 from 1990.

Art. 98.  Special hours will be granted to the student employee, when proven incompatibility between school hours and department hours, without prejudice to the exercise of the position.


§ 2o  Special hours will also be granted to employees with disabilities, when the need is proven by an official medical board, regardless of time compensation.

Although the article talks about a civil servant that is a student, it seems that the general interpretation is that it applies to all civil servants and not just students.  (But I have no experience, so please advise on that, too, if you can.)

§ 3o The provisions contained in § 2 are extended to civil servants who have a spouse, child or dependent with a disability.                     (Wording given by Law No. 13,370, of 2016)

The specific situation that has made doctors concede such recommendation is that the civil servant is parent of a child with a handicap that requires the reduction.
Question. Is this special work schedule stated by article 98 a form of "medical license" that article 83 (of the same law) talks about?

Art. 83. Leave may be granted to a civil servant due to illness of their spouse or partner, parents, children, stepfather or stepmother and stepson, or a dependent who lives at their expense and is included in their functional settlement, subject to proof by official medical expertise.

The document presented is definitely an official doctor's document (signed by three well-identified doctors employed by the government).
I believe this is an easy question, but I have no experience with how I can classify a document within the law.
Question. Another way to ask the question is---how can I tell from a doctor's recommendation document that I'm looking at a "medical license"?

So are you asking whether the document signed by the doctors satisfies "proof by official medical expertise"?


Although the article talks about a civil servant that is a student, it
seems that the general interpretation is that it applies to all civil
servants and not just students.

No, that just applies to student civil servants, or servants who are themselves handicapped or have a handicapped closed relative (spouse or children), in the exact terms of the articles you cited. As per § 4o, servants who do some specific academic tasks can claim special hours as well.

Question. Is this special work schedule stated by article 98 a form of "medical license" that article 83 (of the same law) talks
about?

No, it's not. A medical license allows a servant not to work. It's different from the special hours, which allow a servant to work in a reduced schedule.

Question. Another way to ask the question is---how can I tell from a doctor's recommendation document that I'm looking at a "medical license"?

I believe the document you are referring to is a official medical board report. I've never seen such a document, so I can't help you much here.
